# Is anything wrong with my manual implementation of Basic HTTP Authentication?

Tags: wcf, authentication, http-authentication, basic-authentication

I am using WCF to develop a RESTful Web Service that acts as a proxy to a set of stored procedures that, for security reasons, cannot be directly accessed by Internet-facing applications.

The class implementing the service's `DataContract` has a helper property that retrieves the name of the currently logged-in user, or generates an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response if no user is currently logged in.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{    
    // The helper property
    string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            WebOperationContext context = WebOperationContext.Current;
            if (context != null)
            {
                string authHeader = context.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
                if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
                {
                    string string64 = authHeader.Substring(6);
                    byte[] array64 = Convert.FromBase64String(string64);
                    string decoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(array64);
                    string[] authParts = decoded.Split(':');

                    if (ValidateLogin(authParts[0] /*userName*/,
                                      authParts[1] /*password*/))
                        return authParts[0];
                }
            }

            OutgoingWebResponseContext outgoing = context.OutgoingResponse;
            outgoing.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            outgoing.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.WwwAuthenticate] = "Basic";
            return null;
        }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public int LengthOfUserName()
    {
        return UserName.Length;
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to log in with a valid user name and password, I still get an Unauthorized error. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you unable to debug your service?

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst: When I debug it with the WCF Test Client, I don't really know what's going on. And I don't know what other options I have.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I was having the same problem, then read something that sounded like you can't set the StatusCode in WCF.

Comment: @bpeikes: I gave up on Web development loooooooooooong ago, and, as a result, lead a much happier life.